# What will this C++ function do when run?

Tags: c++

Can anybody tell me what the following function `send_signal` will do in real terms? I'm assuming it will send 1 million bytes of data to `COM2`, but that doesn't appear to match up with its real world implementation.

**Update.** The hardware on COM2 is a robotic arm and the function in question triggers the arm. However, the arm action only lasts for circa 10 seconds - but I'm guessing that 1 million bytes of data will take longer than 10 seconds to send and thus would trigger multiple actions (but it doesn't).

```cpp
#define TXDATA 0x2F8 // COM2
#define SIGNAL 0x00  // This value gives +12V for 1 milli second

void send_signal(void)
{
 long count;
 
    for (count = 0; count < 1000000; count++)   
         _outp(TXDATA, (char) (SIGNAL + SIGNAL));
         
}
```

Comment: Well I wouldn't expect it to do anything with C#, for one thing. Please could you edit the tags on your question to only specify the languages it actually relates to?

Comment: Do you have the documentation or source code for `_outp()`?

Comment: @ShaneBishop https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/outp-outpw-outpd

Comment: @CDR -- I think you need to edit the tags in the question to specify the operating system, hardware, and other pertinent information.  There is no `_outp` function in modern Windows (if that's what you're using).  Just having a tag of `C++` raises all sorts of questions that need not be raised.

Comment: What data rate is uart set to?  Is it a USB device.  
Rate is in bit so it USB is 57K assume 10 bits per bye the rate would be 5.7KB. So transfer would take around 200 seconds.

Comment: Show the datasheet for the robotic arm as well - otherwise we're guessing at what logic is going on at the other end.

Answer (score 2):

On an appropriate embedded system, it will indeed place one million bytes in the COM2 transmitter holding register.  Since it does so faster than the port can actually transmit them, most of them will be lost.  To actually send all one million bytes, it is necessary to read the status register and check for bit 5 (THR is empty) before copying each byte.

On a computer running a modern OS, it will fault because userspace is not permitted direct access to I/O ports, it has to go through a driver.

Answer (score 0):

It calls the [`_outp`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/outp-outpw-outpd?view=msvc-160) function with `0x2F8` as first argument and `0x00`  as second argument one milion times.

Without context one can only speculate. My guess would be for it to set a high state on COM2 for a certain amount of time.

Comment: Thanks. The hardware on COM2 is a robotic arm and the function in question triggers the arm. However, the arm action only lasts for ~10 seconds. I'm assuming 1 million bytes of data will take longer than 10 seconds to send.

Comment: @CDR: Don't assume, calculate.  What is the baud rate?

Comment: @BenVoigt the hardware is over 10 years old and I'm struggling to find the correct BAUD rate.

Answer (score 0):

this code send 1000000 of 0x00 in the 0x2F8 port

attention this `_outp` functions is obsolete